# HQL generated a incorrect SQL query

Tags: sql, hql

I got `[42000] You have an error in your SQL syntax` error when I execute the HQL below:

`update Status set result=18 where (userByUserId.userName like 'administrator')`

And this is the corresponding SQL:

```
update
    status cross 
join

set
    result=18 
where
    userName like 'administrator'
```

The results I am getting are incorrect.

---

But another similar query is in working order:

`select count(*) from Status where (userByUserId.userName like 'administrator')`

the corresponding SQL:

```
select
    count(*) as col_0_0_ 
from
    status status0_ cross 
join
    user user1_ 
where
    status0_.userId=user1_.userId 
    and (
        user1_.userName like 'administrator'
    )
```

---

Does anyone know what happened?

---

Here is the code(partly):

Status.java

```
@Table(name = "status")
@Entity
@KeyField("statusId")
public class Status implements Serializable {
  private Integer result;

  @Column(name = "result", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true
      , length = 10, precision = 0)
  @Basic
  public Integer getResult() {
    return result;
  }

  private Integer userId;

  @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true
    , length = 10, precision = 0)
  public Integer getUserId() {
    return userId;
  }

  public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
  }

  private User userByUserId;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "userId", nullable = false,
      insertable = false, updatable = false)
  public User getUserByUserId() {
    return userByUserId;
  }
}
```

User.java

```
@Table(name = "user")
@Entity
@KeyField("userId")
public class User implements Serializable {

  private String userName;

  @Column(name = "userName", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 24,
    precision = 0, unique = true)
  @Basic
  public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
  }

  private Collection<Status> statusesByUserId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userByUserId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  public Collection<Status> getStatusesByUserId() {
    return statusesByUserId;
  }
}
```

Comment: If that SQL was generated by Hibernate, then you have probably got an incorrect mapping file as it's rubbish. Can you post your mapping file for table Status?

Comment: I had appended some code in my question, thanks for you help!

Comment: Using `like` without wildcards doesn't really make sense.